# $L^p$ boundedness of Riesz potential.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Why studying, I repeatedly see people use the following result. That is there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$\|\nabla \Delta^{-1}\nabla \times u\|_p \le C \|u\|_p$$
for every $u \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^3)$. Here $p > 1$.

The reference I got so far for the above estimate is the book "Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions" of Stein, E.M., especially chapter II. However, I cannot find exactly which results there to apply.

Would anyone give me some hints? Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Stein: Chapter III is all about Riesz transforms. Note that the formal Fourier transform of the operator $ \nabla \triangle^{-1} \nabla\times$ is a multiplier of the form $x_i x_j / |x|^2$ and is a homogeneous function of degree 0.

---

In terms of general theory, the $L^p$ boundedness of Riesz transforms is a standard/motivating application of Calderon-Zygmund Theory and can be viewed as a result of the [Mikhlin-Hormander Multiplier Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_integral_operators_of_convolution_type#Multiplier_theorem). If you like to see a different approach in getting this result, you can look at Terry Tao's old [Math 254A notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/) from the Winter 2001 term. Weak 3 covers Littlewood-Paley theory and then derives some portion of Calderon-Zygmund theory including the multiplier theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest, at the time I posted this question, I dont know why we call that operator is kind of Reisz transform. Thanks to your answer, I understand it now. Your answer is throughfully and I learn much from it. Now, at least I see an application of multiplier theorems (I dont work much about harmonic analysis). :)